# jquery: how do I access an array element in a jquery object

Tags: jquery, arrays, object

Heres the problem.  I am building a jquery program that lets me create and position divs on a drawing area.
I need to keep track of the divs, their location, CSS proterties and other details. So, I am creating an object that contains an array of all these items for each div.

This is the code fragment for creating the object.

```
var divData= {items: [
{ID: "21", Block: "Block_01", posX : "450", posY : "540" },
{ID: "43", Block: "Block_02", posX : "250", posY : "440" },
{ID: "46", Block: "Block_03", posX : "50", posY : "54" },
{ID: "54", Block: "Block_04", posX : "140", posY : "210" },
{ID: "55", Block: "Block_05", posX : "900", posY : "820" },
{ID: "79", Block: "Block_06", posX : "380", posY : "520" }
]};
```

And this is the code that I have written to display the contents of the array.

```
alert ('array length is : ' + divData.items.length);
```

This statement returns a value of 6 which is correct, Also, I can push data into the array with this statement the alert statement now says 7.

```
divData.items.push({ID: "266", Block: "Block_01", posX : "450", posY : "540" });
```

The problem is when I try to display the contents of the array with the following code, nothing happens.

```
for (var i=0;i<divData.items.length;i++)
{
document.write(divData.items[i] + "<br>");
}
```

The output on the screen is this [object Object] seven times.

What am I doing wrong?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'items' in your array are objects. You can't output an object on the screen directly. You have to specify which property of the object you are trying to access:

```
for (var i = 0;i < divData.items.length; i++)
{
  document.write(divData.items[i].ID + "<br/>"); // access the OBJECT's property!
}
```

You may want to do *something* like:

```
for (var i = 0;i < divData.items.length; i++)
{
  $("#container").append("<div class='positionedDiv' id='" + divData.items[i].ID + "' style='top: " + divData.items[i].posY + "px;left:" + divData.items[i].posX + "px;></div>");
}
```

Some CSS:

```
.positionedDiv {
  position: absolute; 
}
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks so much, I just didn't make the obvious connection.  Thanks so much.

Comment: Just of interest, how would I delete a row?

Comment: @Chris: If this answers your question, then make sure to upvote the answer and mark it as accepted. :)